# I want to change value in json array object based on index number using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to change value in json array object based on index number using pyspark, then will use columnName to update dataframe column names:

**input:**

```py
jsonArray = [
    {
        "index": 1,
        "columnName":"Names"
    },
        {
        "index": 2,
        "columnName":"City"
    }
    ]
```

**output:**

```py
jsonArray = [
    {
        "index": 1,
        "columnName":"titles"
    },
        {
        "index": 2,
        "columnName":"countries"
    }
    ]
```

**function header:**

```py
def renameColumn(index, newName, df):
    return df_with_new_column_names
```

Comment: What's the use case of `renameColumn` function ? How is it relevant to `jsonArray`?

Comment: for right now, I want replace "columnName" value in jsonArray using Python or Pyspark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def jsonColumnName(jsonArray, indx, newName):
   for jsonObj in jsonArray:
       if jsonObj['index'] == indx:
           jsonObj['Field_Name'] = newName
   return jsonArray
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly, try something as below-

```
for i in range(len(jsonArray)):
  if jsonArray[i]['index']==1:
    jsonArray[i]['columnName'] = "titles"
  else:
    jsonArray[i]['columnName'] = "countries"
  
print(jsonArray)
```

**Output** -

```
[{'index': 1, 'columnName': 'titles'}, {'index': 2, 'columnName': 'countries'}]
```